# How to make responsive images on CDN and without loosing SEO

Tags: image, seo, responsive-design

So I'm doing a pre-study on how to implement a responsive design to an existing site with a lot of images. These images would be nice if we could serve differently to the visitor according to device size, pixel ratio and/or bandwidth.

The site is using Akamai as a CDN so we must have a solution that uses different URLs for different image sizes. Doing this by Javascript is fine, we require it anyway.

I was looking at CSS-tricks spreadsheet (http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/) and specifically Foresight.js (https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js) seemed to be the right stuff for us.

Basicly the markup would look something like this:

```
<img data-src="/images/imagefile.jpg" data-width="320" data-height="240" class="fs-img">
<noscript>
    <img src="/images/imagefile.jpg">
</noscript>
```

But then I noticed that Google will ignore any fallback images placed within  tags. This could be devastating to our SEO since the images from the press room are essential to be indexed by Google et al.

So my question is, how do you serve SEO friendly-enough images responsively? Is removing the src-attribute killing SEO? There will still be all the other attributes, the alt-one most important I guess.

Answer (score 0):

yea, image alt tag is very important from search engine optimization point of view. Here there is no harm to resize the image by considering devices or element. Make sure you use meaningful image name to get them up in image search result of Google.

Comment: But you don't want to load any "wrong" image to later replace with the "right" one, and guessing which one to write in the mark-up upfront is not possible... If we didn't sit behind the CDN we could send a cookie to the backend and then select what image to serve but that will not work with the caching...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

I don't really feel that you =need to "alt" tag all of the copies. From SEO point of view this is both redundant and somewhat spammy (imagine Google's response to a website in which each URL holds 5 [or more] different sized version of the same image, all with the same exact alt tags... )

Allowing Goolge to Recognize tags of the "default size" image should be enough for your SEO purposes.

Another workaround I can think of is to always have live links to all the different sizes (while presenting only one personalized version)
I`m not sure if its feasible, but you don't have to many version or want to present a few selected ones, this will do.

This will not solve the alt tag issue, but at least they all be crawled and indexed separately.
Also, alt tag is really over-rated. Speaking from almost 10 years of experience I can say that is's effect is marginal, at best. Especially if you link to the image includes the relevant KW.

If still worried, you can link to a different HTML page, containing said image and alt tag it there but it sound like too much trouble to me...

Comment: I completely for only alt-tagging one copy. But can I put an alt-tag on the src-less tag and expect good SEO?

Comment: Loading the "default" image is completely out of bonds, that's what the whole idea of responsive images are trying to avoid.